# Find the Max value of a column based on the value of the other column in Spark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, max, window-functions

I have the following dataframe where the third column is "clickedAirbnb" and fourth column is "rank"

```
|    Tom|             Paris|             |                 1|
|    Tom|            Mumbai|             |                 1|
|    Tom|          Stockolm|             |                 1|
|    Tom|              Oslo|      airbnb1|                 2|
|    Tom|             Tokyo|      airbnb1|                 2|
|    Tom|         Bangalore|      airbnb1|                 2|
|    Sam|             Seoul|     airbnb11|                 1|
|    Sam|             Tokyo|     airbnb11|                 1|
|    Sam|            Berlin|     airbnb12|                 2|
|    Sam|         Bangalore|     airbnb12|                 2|
|    Sam|         Singapore|     airbnb12|                 2|
|    Sam|              Oslo|      airbnb2|                 3|
|    Sam|         Amsterdam|      airbnb2|                 3|
|    Sam|         Bangalore|      airbnb2|                 3|
```

I would like to return those where column "clickedAirbnb" contains empty values and the max on the column "rank" is less than 2.
Here is what I tried but does not work (complains of invalid operation on column)

```scala
val result1and2 = result.where(col("clickedAirbnb").contains("")
                            && max(col("rank")) <= 2)
```

Is there a way to compute the maximum value on a column?

UPDATE:
To back up a bit, the result df is computed like this:

```scala
val window = Window.partitionBy(df1("User")).orderBy(df1("clickedAirbnb"))
val result = df1.withColumn("clickedDestHotRank", dense_rank().over(window))
```

Now return those users where clickedAirbnb (third column) is empty and rank (4th column)'s max value does not exceed 2

```scala
val result2 = result.where(col("clickedAirbnb").contains("")
                        && (max(col("rank")) <=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want:

- to group only those that have no value in *clickedAirbnb*
- return the group if and only if its *max(rank)<=2*

Something like that, maybe:

```
//those that have no value in clickedAirbnb
val resultTmp = result.where(col("clickedAirbnb")==="")

//is its max("rank")<=2 ?  
val b = resultTmp.select(max("rank")<=2).first().getBoolean(0)  

if(b){
  resultTmp.show()
}
```

Hope I understood well.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> sc = spark.sparkContext
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ['Tom','Paris','',1],
    ['Tom','Mumbai','',1],
    ['Tom','Stockolm','',1],
    ['Tom','Oslo','airbnb1',2],
    ['Tom','Tokyo','airbnb1',2],
    ['Tom','Bangalore','airbnb1',2],
    ['Sam','Seoul','airbnb11',1],
    ['Sam','Tokyo','airbnb11',1],
    ['Sam','Berlin','airbnb12',2],
    ['Sam','Bangalore','airbnb12',2],
    ['Sam','Singapore','airbnb12',2],
    ['Sam','Oslo','airbnb2',3],
    ['Sam','Amsterdam','airbnb2',3],
    ['Sam','Bangalore','airbnb2',3]
])

>>> df = rdd.toDF(['name','city','clickedAirbnb', 'rank'])
>>> df.show()
+----+---------+-------------+----+
|name|     city|clickedAirbnb|rank|
+----+---------+-------------+----+
| Tom|    Paris|             |   1|
| Tom|   Mumbai|             |   1|
| Tom| Stockolm|             |   1|
| Tom|     Oslo|      airbnb1|   2|
| Tom|    Tokyo|      airbnb1|   2|
| Tom|Bangalore|      airbnb1|   2|
| Sam|    Seoul|     airbnb11|   1|
| Sam|    Tokyo|     airbnb11|   1|
| Sam|   Berlin|     airbnb12|   2|
| Sam|Bangalore|     airbnb12|   2|
| Sam|Singapore|     airbnb12|   2|
| Sam|     Oslo|      airbnb2|   3|
| Sam|Amsterdam|      airbnb2|   3|
| Sam|Bangalore|      airbnb2|   3|
+----+---------+-------------+----+

>>> df.where(col("clickedAirbnb") == "").where(col("rank") <= 2).show()
+----+--------+-------------+----+
|name|    city|clickedAirbnb|rank|
+----+--------+-------------+----+
| Tom|   Paris|             |   1|
| Tom|  Mumbai|             |   1|
| Tom|Stockolm|             |   1|
+----+--------+-------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to describe a more general case. From the following example, we want to pick "value" based on max of "order".

```scala
val df = Seq(("v1", 3), ("v2", 3), ("v3", 2)).toDF("value", "order")
df.show()
// +-----+-----+
// |value|order|
// +-----+-----+
// |   v1|    3|
// |   v2|    3|
// |   v3|    2|
// +-----+-----+
```

2 ways to go:

- If you only have 1 value per order OR if you don't care which 1 value you will get as long as it corresponds to max of "order" column, use either of these:

  ```scala
  // Spark 3.3+
  df.groupBy().agg(max_by("value", "order")).show()
  // +--------------------+
  // |max_by(value, order)|
  // +--------------------+
  // |                  v2|
  // +--------------------+

  // Spark 3.0+
  df.groupBy().agg(expr("max_by(value, order)")).show()
  ```

  ```scala
  import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
  df.withColumn("_rn", row_number().over(Window.orderBy(desc("order"))))
    .filter("_rn=1").select("value").show()
  // +-----+
  // |value|
  // +-----+
  // |   v1|
  // +-----+
  ```
- If you have more values per order/ you need consistency/ ability to further debug, use this:

  ```scala
  import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
  df.withColumn("_rank", rank().over(Window.orderBy(desc("order"))))
    .filter("_rank=1").select("value").show()
  // +-----+
  // |value|
  // +-----+
  // |   v1|
  // |   v2|
  // +-----+
  ```

Answer (score -1):

> Register a temp table and then write the desired query

```
your_data_frame.registerTempTable("table1");

res = sqlCtx.sql("select * where clickedAirbnb = "" and max(rank)<=2 from table1) ;
```